# Verification of proof involving logarithms and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-verification

> **Question:**  Consider $E_n\in(0,1)$ and $E_n\to0,\text{as }n\to\infty$
>
> Assuming that $E_{n+1} = E_n E_{n-1}$, show that, for a real $C$ independent of $n$, $$E_{n+1} \leq C{E_n}^\phi$$ where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the Golden Ratio

**My attempt so far:**

We can take logarithms of both side to see that

\begin{align*}\log(E_{n+1}) &= \log(E_n E_{n-1})\\
&=\log(E_n)+\log(E_{n-1})\end{align*}

We can see that this fulfils the conditions of the Fibonacci Sequence, $F_{n+1} = F_{n}+F_{n-1}$

Therefore, we can assume that $$\frac{\log(E_{n+1})}{\log(E_n)}\to \phi,\quad\text{as }n\to\infty$$

We can then say that \begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\log(E_{n+1})}{\log(E_n)}-\phi\right|&=0\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\log(E_{n+1})-\phi\log(E_n)\right|&=0\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\log(E_{n+1}) -\log({E_n}^\phi)\right|&=0\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|E_{n+1} - {E_n}^\phi\right|&=1\end{align*}

I'm not entirely sure that the last line of this is correct - I have attempted to get rid of the logarithms as I would have done in an equation with no limits or absolute values in. Could someone let me know if I have done anything wrong please. I am also struggling to continue from this point so any guidance would be much appreciated too.

Comment: I don't think that you can replace $\log(E_{n+1})-\log(E_n^\phi)$ like that.

Comment: I also don't think that you can multiply both sides by $\log(E_n)$ near the bottom, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(E_n)=\log(0^+)=-\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks for your input, how would you propose I tackle this question then?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
The following functional equation :
$$f(n+1)=f(n)f(n-1)$$
Have to solution :
$$f(n)=e^{c_1F_n+c_2L_n}$$
Where $F_n$ are the Fibonnaci number , $L_n$ the Lucas number and $c_1$,$c_2$ are arbitrary parameters.